Screenshot of the Week #115
This contest is over.
previous contest | next contest
Hello and welcome to the 115th edition of the Screenshot of the Week!
To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! Clockwork's delicious looking picture from final-fantasy-15 won with 23 upvotes!


To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
Stack Exchange’s Code of Conduct still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.
How long will the contest run?
We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2024-05-13, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.
After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2024-05-20, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

No Theme
There is no theme this week.
As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a question of its own.  Additionally, there is the hall of fame you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

I think my next submission will just be a screenshot of a relatively unknown game

For anyone wondering why the widget hasn't been updated, it's a bug with the sidebar widget that arose as a result of the networks migration away from imgur. There's a meta post about the bug, so hopefully it'll be resolved soon.

@Wipqozn we completely skipped a widget screenshot, sadly the bug is still present

@pinckerman I just checked - looks like it works now (despite the Meta bug post not being updated).

@TimmyJim good to know

Ethereal view of an alien structure from no-mans-sky


Uhhhh, that's just Sputnik.

@TimmyJim so Russia is the Atlas? Mother of God D:

This Stargate-looking object caught my eye in the-planet-crafter


Shadowheart and the Shadow-cursed Sea:

After answering this question I just had to revisit a few places in baldurs-gate-3 :)

Baldurs Gate 3 is PS 5 only ?

@nobody No, why?

For PS 4 at least not.

@nobody I wasn't sure if something about my post made you question it, but it seems you're just asking :) See e.g. the Wikipedia entry for the supported platforms: Windows, PlayStation 5, macOS, and Xbox Series X/S.

Yes i was Just asking. Thanks for the link. ☺️

another-crabs-treasure
For all your seafood, meat, vegetable, and eldritch horror seasoning needs!


I lol'ed at "elden bay" and the blatantly ripped off Old Bay design.

mmm, BPA additives

Tifa killing a dragon final-fantasy-7-rebirth


"Lonely Bit of Sunshine"
From a modded 1.19.2 minecraft-java-edition survival world with the lovely BYG and Terralith terrain generation mods and Quadral resource pack! Modded world gen never ceases to amaze :)


Queue Dire Dire Docks/Jolly roger Bay music

Expedition night in forewarned


I think you should go north. It might be safer.

Estelle Bright in trails-of-cold-steel-iv making Theodore Roosevelt's Big stick ideology quite literal


and if you want to know how bad that big stick hits, just ask Olivier how it felt after being smashed back into a restaurant with it

I think you meant to write "of" instead of "od-cold-steel"

@Clockwork thank you

A little riddle. Where are the food thiefs  final-fantasy-9


"Some things we can't change. We can only move on from where we are."

shadowrun-dragonfall

The game first came out as a DLC, titled Shadowrun: Dragonfall for the game Shadowrun Returns and later on got released as a standalone title as Shadowrun: Dragonfall - Director's Cut
